# Drop a table in Postgres that is referenced by another

Tags: postgresql

In `MySQL` I have a nice way to suppress key checking, I just do it like this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

After that I could easily drop any table. I thought, that in `Postgresql` I could do the same if I run:

```
SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
```

But the problem is, when I try to drop some tables after that, I get a list of errors, saying that some table depends on another table blablabla. So, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `set constraints` to actually **drop** a table with constraints. Just use `drop table .. cascade`. If you did mean `delete` rather than `drop` then for this to work, you need to run everything in *one* transaction **and** you need to have all constraints defined as `deferrable`. **Edit** your question and show us the `create table` statements of all tables involved, the statements that generated the error and the **exact** error message.

Comment: Maybe `drop table xyz CASCADE;` blablabla?

Comment: It is hard for me to show the `create table` statement, because I'm working on a remote server. But it may important to know, that I have two tables, where one table has a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` referencing a field from another table.

Comment: What I want is to `DROP` a table.

Comment: I've just tested it and your solution `drop table ... cascade` seems to work.

Comment: This would have been obvious from the start if you had included the `drop` statement that you tried and the **exact** error message you got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;` is only valid for DML statements (`insert`, `update`, `delete`) and **only** if the affected foreign keys were defined with `deferrable`.

As you want to **drop** the table (not delete rows), deferred constraints are irrelevant. To drop a table that is the target of a foreign key, use:

```
drop table foobar CASCADE;
```

this will drop the table foobar and any foreign key *referencing* that table (and obviously and foreign key where foobar references another table).

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html